# Value in view not updating after $promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I have a value in my view that is not updating after a service method is called.

Here is the relevant code in the controller:

```
$scope.remaining = 20;

AcctService.getCurrentCount.get(calculateRemaining); //This is a $resource method

function calculateRemaining(result) {
    $scope.remaining -= result;
    alert($scope.remaining);
}
```

Here is the code for `.getCurrentCount`:

```
service.getCurrentCount = $resource('/api/getCount', {}, {
        'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
    });
```

With the above code, say for example the `result` returned is 5. "15" will be alerted. However, in the view, `{{remaining}}` is still 20. No errors, the view just doesn't update.

I have tried the following:

- $timeout - nothing different happens
- Making `$scope.remaining` an object with property "value". (I read in another post about issues with data binding of primitives vs references). No difference.
- $promise and .then() - no difference
- $apply results in a digest error

Note, I am also coding with Ionic, not sure if it makes a difference. I disabled caching in the Ionic config, and another service method that returns an array propagates an ng-repeat as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Show view context. Using primitives is most likely issue.

Comment: Is the `{{remaining}}` part in a directive or ng-included html by any chance? I'm thinking maybe there's a child scope at play here that's inherited the `20` from its parent, then the parent value gets modified (but not the child that the view is referencing).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what things look like inside that `get()` function, but it doesn't look right.
Assuming `get()` returns a promise, you should write it like this:

```
AcctService.getCurrentCount.get().then(calculateRemaining); //This is a $resource method
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my post with the code for .getCurrentcount: 


    `service.getCurrentCount = $resource('/api/getCount', {}, {
        'get': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
    });`



Unfortunately using .then did not work.

Comment: According to the docs, the syntax for `get()` is like this: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error]), so you'd write `AcctService.getCurrentCount.get(undefined, calculateRemaining);`
The first argument is the data you send to the server with the GET request.
If you actually do need to send data, then of course that would replace `undefined`

Comment: parameters are optional and OP code should work fine. it's already alerting returned value

Comment: Thanks HankScorpio as @charlietfl mentioned, the updated `$scope.remaining` value is being alerted, so the success function is firing. But `$scope.remaining` doesn't update in the view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to create get method to return array. Use default 'query' method of $resource. And first parameter for the method is an object of parameters. second one is success function. So change you service to this

```
service.getCurrentCount = $resource('/api/getCount');
```

And later use it as

```
AcctService.getCurrentCount.query({},calculateRemaining);
```

Also check if you are not using one way data binding {{::remaining}}

And also you have to make sure you are using right $scope, to check that make "remaining" a field of an object. You can do it this way:

```
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.myData.remaining = 20;
```

and later at the controller initialize it the same and at the html

```
{{myData.remaining}}
```

also you can use $scope.apply(); but actually that is used at different case

Comment: Thanks @Yernar for the response. Good call on the default .query() method, I'm now using that instead. However, the view is still not updating unfortunately. The success function does execute, and the updated $scope.remaining is alerted, but it doesn't get updated in the view.